# Преобразование списка в строковом представлении в обычный список

Tags: python, переменные

Я уже ни раз сталкивался с такой проблемой: у меня есть строковая переменная в виде `'["numer",9,197,"uyt"]'`. Можно заметить, что это строка со списком. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать её в список?

split() не поможет, так как зачастую в кавычках находятся словари в словаре в списке в словаре (в общем, весьма трудная конструкция, которую так просто методом split() не преобразовать)

Comment: У меня сразу вопрос: а почему у вас вообще возникают такие строковые переменные? Откуда они?

Comment: Я занимаюсь парсингом сайтов. И произошла ситуация, что нужно брать данные с технической страницы, где они представлены маштабным словарём. К сожалению, при парсинге получить его словарём не получится

Comment: Может всё же json, а не словарь?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос что строки их интернета. Это сильно влияет на правильный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй функцию eval

```
data_str = '["number", 9]'
data_list = eval(data_str)
```

Comment: Хочу уточнить, что способ с модулем json от Владимира тоже работает, единственное - выражение json.loads(var) нужно обернуть в переменную

Comment: И надейтесь, что не спарсите какую-нибудь бяку, которую запустите через eval :)

Comment: Да, такой вариант подходит, если в строке — валидное Python-выражение.

Comment: Откуда бы в строке с сайта быть правильному коду на Питоне?

Comment: Избегайте `eval` как чумы. [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) решает задачу безопасно.

Answer (score 3):

Если в этом переменной содержится валидный JSON, то можно выполнить т. н. десериализацию — восстановление Python-объекта из строки:

```
import json
var = '["numer",9,197,"uyt"]'
try:
    result = json.loads(var)
    print(result)
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print('Невалидный JSON')
```

Результат:

```
['numer', 9, 197, 'uyt']
```

Обратите внимание на try-except. Он подскажет вам, если в какой-то момент в этих строках будет невалидный JSON.